# Android InCallScreen is hidden when I open activity in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent

Ok. I am finding it difficult to put it clearly. Let me try.

I am using a broadcast receiver to be invoked for every call.

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.example.receiveCall"
    android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And in the onReceive method i am starting an activity on top.

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

            Handler mHandler = new Handler();
            AttendActivity.ctx = context;
            Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // do what you need to do here after the delay
//                  context.startService(new Intent(context, AutoAnswerIntentService.class));
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context,
                            AttendActivity.class)
                            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

                }
            };
            mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 500);
        }       
    }
```

This works fine when the app is not visible. But when the app is visible. My activity opens on top of InCallScreen. but when I close the AttendActivity. Instead of InCallScreen my app is visible. And the Incallscreen is on top of it.

Could you help me fix this please. 
Desired output

MyApp -> InCallScreen -> AttendActivity

Current output
InCallScreen -> MyApp -> AttendActivity

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to read this [article](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html). It has tons of information about Activities, Tasks, Applications and processes in Android.

My guess would be that your AttendActivity has default task affinity. This means that if this activity shown then your whole task (which is most likely all of your app's activities) will be bring to front.

You can change this behavior. You need to android:taskAffinity on your activity in the Manifest.

As example, you can put android:taskAffinity="" for AttendActivity in manifest. This way when it will be brought to front, it won't drag whole application with it.